# What is the best way to find out the number of Tabs in a TabActivity?

Tags: android, tabactivity

I create tabs dynamically in a TabActivity. 
Is there a simple way to ask for the number of existing Tabs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe a bit of a workaround, but you should be able to use: `getTabHost().getTabWidget().getTabCount()`.

I just tested this in my app and it worked correctly.

See here for more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html#getTabCount()

Answer (score 7):

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    int totalTabs = tabLayout.getTabCount();
```

Answer (score 3):

To get number of Tab Use

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount() // tabHost is the instance of TabHost
```